# How to programmatically get associated webparts of sharepoint list?

Tags: .net, asp.net, sharepoint, moss, wss

Using  SPList I want to get all the webpart urls that associated with the list.
Is it possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The only way this would be possible is to loop through all pages in all SPWeb's, then get each page's webpartmanager reference, then loop through all webparts and check the properties of the webpart.

Comment: If you are talking about searching all the properties tagged as WebBrowsable within each web part and seeing if it's a list name thats been set, it would work probably.

Answer (score 1):

```
SPWeb finweb = site.OpenWeb().Webs["finance"];
SPWeb Q12010Web = finweb.Webs["Q2FY2010"];
SPList Lib10K = Q12010Web.Lists["10K Document Tasks"];
var views = Lib10K.Views["All Items"];
SPView allitemsform = Lib10K.Views["All Items"];
SPLimitedWebPartManager mgr = Q12010Web.GetLimitedWebPartManager(allitemsform.Url,     PersonalizationScope.Shared);
SPLimitedWebPartManager mgr1 = Q12010Web.GetLimitedWebPartManager("default.aspx", PersonalizationScope.Shared);
```

if you notice, mgr1 will only reference the web